# "bash: git--version: command not found"

Tags: git

I have downloaded GIT on my windows computer but when I type "git--version", it gives me "bash: git--version: command not found".

```
`$ env|grep PATH
HOMEPATH=\Users\shaggy
MANPATH=/mingw64/share/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/share/man:/usr/man:/share/man:
PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:/c/Users/shaggy/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/shaggy/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/iCLS Client:/c/Program Files/Intel/iCLS Client:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/cmd:/bin/git.exe:/cmd:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
EXEPATH=C:\Program Files\Git
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/mingw64/lib/pkgconfig:/mingw64/share/pkgconfig
ACLOCAL_PATH=/mingw64/share/aclocal:/usr/share/aclocal
INFOPATH=/usr/local/info:/usr/share/info:/usr/info:/share/info:
`
```

Comment: Your git path is probably not configured on your CMD. There will be a seperate GIT CLI, try use that.

Comment: Thank you ..problem solved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `git --version`  instead of `git--version`

Notice space between git command and its argument. Novice mistake, don't worry about it :)